# Write data to firebase when clicking on a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to update a child note in firebase when I click on an object in a RecyclerView, but I can't get it to work. I'm pulling down and populating the ReyclerView correctly. What I need is when I click on an object I want the "selected" child in firebase to be updated to true for that specific task. From the start the selected child is false and hiding an image and when I click on a object in the Reyclerview it should be updated to true so the image is shown. I hope you understand what I'm looking for and can help me.

Firebase Structure

```
"groups": {
    groupKey: {
        "task": { 
             taskKey: {
                 "selected": "true"
             }
         }
    }
}
```

This is what I got:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mDBRef = mDatabase.getReference().child("groups").child(projectID);
    mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("groups").child(projectID).child("task");

mDBRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            taskList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                Boolean selected = (Boolean) snapshot.child("selected").getValue();

                TaskDataService taskDataService = new TaskDataService();
                taskDataService.setSelected(selected);

                taskList.add(taskDataService);

                taskRecyclerAdapter = new TaskRecyclerAdapter(Project.this, taskList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(taskRecyclerAdapter);
                taskRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                DatabaseReference updateTaskToDB = mDatabaseReference.push();

                Map<String, Object> taskToSave = new HashMap<>();
                taskToSave.put("selected", taskDataService.getSelected());
                updateTaskToDB.setValue(taskToSave);

            }
        }
});
```

RecyclerAdapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final TaskDataService dataService = serviceList.get(position);
    holder.imgCheckStatus = dataService.getSelected();

    if (dataService.getSelected() == false) {
        holder.checkImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {

    }

    holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dataService.setSelected(true);
            Log.d("CLICK", String.valueOf(dataService.getSelected()));
        }
    });
}
```

DataService

```
public Boolean selected;
public Boolean getSelected() {
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(Boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}
```

Comment: There is lots of examples how can you get position of clicked view in adapter by creating and implementing `interfaces`. Obtaining that position than you can get data from `list`. And second thing consider using Firebase UI in that and similar scenarios:
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

Answer (score 0):

Instead of,

```
holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dataService.setSelected(true);
        Log.d("CLICK", String.valueOf(dataService.getSelected()));
    }
});
```

In your ViewHolder class use this in constructor,

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               //handle your click event here
            }
        });
```

Here you can use `getAdapterPosition()` method to retrieve position of clicked item and use to get data from List like this `tasklist.get(getAdapterPosition())` and set `selected` to `true` then you can store it in firebase database.

moreover, try to avoid handle any click events to **onBindViewHolder** either you put it in **onCreateViewHolder** or in your **ViewHolder** class. on my personal experience it improve the performance of RecyclerView Since allocating memory is very "expensive" all the allocation tasks are performed in on create of RecyclerView.

Hope this helps you.